# Need to alias Inner join column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

```
SELECT AlertTypeID FROM incidentalert 
INNER JOIN incidentalerttype 
ON incidentalert.alerttypeid=incidentalerttype.AlertTypeID
WHERE IncidentID=111210
```

AlertTypeID is a column in table 1, and a primary key in table 2.  How can I disambiguate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ia.AlertTypeID 
FROM
    incidentalert ia 
    inner join incidentalerttype iat on iat.alerttypeid=ia.AlertTypeID
where 
    ia.IncidentID=111210
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply fully qualify the column reference by adding the table name in front. As a best practice, you should do the same for the column in your `WHERE` clause as well. Using aliases for the table names can make this a bit easier to read too.

```
SELECT ia.AlertTypeID 
    FROM incidentalert ia
        INNER JOIN incidentalerttype iat
            ON ia.AlertTypeID = iat.AlertTypeID 
    WHERE ia.IncidentID = 111210
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be refactored as well as aliasing the tables

Here is your original query:

```
SELECT AlertTypeID FROM incidentalert 
INNER JOIN incidentalerttype 
ON incidentalert.alerttypeid=incidentalerttype.AlertTypeID
WHERE IncidentID=111210;
```

Since you are going for only one IncidentID trying retrieving it before the JOIN takes place:

```
SELECT ia.AlertTypeID
FROM
    (SELECT AlertTypeID FROM incidentalert WHERE IncidentID=111210) ia
    INNER JOIN (SELECT AlertTypeID FROM incidentalerttype) iat USING (AlertTypeID)
;
```

This should run much faster as the number of incidents grows.

IF you need all the columns from the incidentalert row change it as follows:

```
SELECT ia.*
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM incidentalert WHERE IncidentID=111210) ia
    INNER JOIN (SELECT AlertTypeID FROM incidentalerttype) iat USING (AlertTypeID)
;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

Just place the table name before the column, just like you do in the JOIN statement.